# Why, when slicing the list, the number of the items in a list is always more than the ending index?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why for example when slicing a list with square brackets in this way

```
spam = [1, 2, 3]
```

When we `print(spam[0:2])` the 3 is not typed while the index of that is 2?

Comment: Why *would* it be included? Python slice and range ends are **ex**clusive, so `spam[:2]` (zero is the default start) means "the first two items".

Comment: http://python-history.blogspot.com/2013/10/why-python-uses-0-based-indexing.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This style of indexing is just very beautiful and comfortable. There're lots of cases where this can be useful. The easiest one is when you have to do something on two halves of an array:

```py
spam = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
center_index = len(spam) / 2
func(spam[center_index:])
func(spam[:center_index])
```

In this example, you don't have to think about +1/-1

Answer (score 0):

Because Python slicing is inclusive @ start and exclusive @ the end